# AKManager Audiokit crash: HALB_IOBufferManager_Client::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of range

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit, xcode12

I am running XCode 12.4 and iOS 13.7. The following, straightforward class

```
import AudioKit
import UIKit


class SoundManager {
    private var sampler: AKAppleSampler
    private var booster: AKBooster
    private var reverb: AKReverb
    private let mixer: AKMixer
    
    required init() {
        sampler = AKAppleSampler()
        booster = AKBooster(sampler, gain: 3.0)
        reverb = AKReverb(booster)
        mixer = AKMixer()
    }
    
    func setup() {
        reverb.loadFactoryPreset(.largeRoom)
        mixer.connect(input: reverb)        
        AKManager.output = mixer
        try? AKManager.start()
    }
}
```

when called

```
let soundManager = SoundManager()
soundManager.setup()
```

crashes with

> HALB_IOBufferManager_Client::GetIOBuffer: the stream index is out of
> range AQME.h:254:IOProcFailure: AQDefaultDevice (1): output stream 0:
> null buffer AQMEIO_HAL.cpp:1774:IOProc: EXCEPTION thrown (-50): error
> != 0

This is something that is crashing on iOS 13.7 simulator but in some 14.x versions doesn't produce a problem. Any idea?

Comment: Have the same using AVPlayer on an iOS13.7 simulator. No problems on iOS14 simulators.

Comment: have you find the solution?

Comment: Have you get the solution. I'm using Xcode 12.5.1 and simulator  XR version 12.4.

Comment: Have the same problem, I am using Xcode 13.2.1 and iOS 13

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this problem occurs on iOS 12 & 13 on the simulator but works fine when running on device. [Source](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667921)